# SQL Scalar Function with Date Convert?

Tags: sql, function, date, null, type-conversion

I am trying to make a scalar function, that will allow me to deal with null dates, which show as 1/1/1900.  I can write out the logic in a query, but when I try to make it a function, whether I return a varchar or a date, it makes the format wrong.

This is the CASE for a column line in a select:

```
CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(f.[DateStart] AS DATE),101) = '01/01/1900' 
THEN '' 
ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(f.[DateStart] AS DATE),101) 
END AS 'DateStart'
```

If I make that a function, like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ConvertDate(@d datetime)
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(@d AS DATE),101) = '01/01/1900' 
            THEN '' 
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(@d AS DATE),101) 
            END);
END
GO
```

I returns a 0 for a legitimate date.  If I return as a date, it returns a good date as 2019-10-08 and returns a null date as 1900-01-01.  Anyone know how to get a function to return the way the case statement runs in the select, the way I want it to?  Just trying to minimize repeating the same long logic throughout all my stored procs.

Thanks!

Comment: Because you're not defining a length to your varchar. Try `returns varchar(10)`. Anyway, try and build it as an inline table valued function, it'll perform much better.

Comment: How do I build it as an inline table valued function? I'm not sure I understand what that is. I will try the varchar(10) and see how that goes.

Comment: A tvf is a function that returns a table. That means the function is set based, rather than row-by-agonizing-row (as a scalar function does). An inline tvf is an especially performant type. If you search online there are many great tutorials and examples.

Comment: Thank you. The varchar(10) return fixed it, so considering the small data set, I can run with it as is.  Thanks for your help! If you want to post that as an answer, I'll mark it so you get the points.